# ErrorException Undefined index: 0 - hhvm and composer

Tags: php, composer-php, hhvm

I'm trying to run:

```
hhvm $(brew --prefix)/bin/composer.phar
```

With:

```
HipHop VM 3.14.3 (rel)
Compiler: 1471660550_N
Repo schema: 90201df99a45497953c42400d58fb97663717b4a
```

But I get:

[image]

Any ideas? Can't really move forward from here. I think it might be similar to: [Error installing XHP with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336034/error-installing-xhp-with-composer)

Running:

```
hhvm composer.phar --verbose
```

I get:

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/AbstractPipes.php:140
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/AbstractPipes.php:140
 Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\AbstractPipes->write() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Pipes/UnixPipes.php:98
 Symfony\Component\Process\Pipes\UnixPipes->readAndWrite() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:1359
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->readPipes() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:1279
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->updateStatus() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:305
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->start() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:201
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:68
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionGuesser.php:94
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionGuesser->guessGitVersion() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionGuesser.php:67
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionGuesser->guessVersion() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Package/Loader/RootPackageLoader.php:76
 Composer\Package\Loader\RootPackageLoader->load() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Factory.php:333
 Composer\Factory->createComposer() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Factory.php:554
 Composer\Factory::create() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Console/Application.php:318
 Composer\Console\Application->getComposer() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Console/Application.php:430
 Composer\Console\Application->getPluginCommands() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Console/Application.php:135
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Console/Application.php:104
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 include() at /Users/alexpchin/work_wordpress/pad-wordpress/composer.phar:24
```

### Update

If I add a version `"version": "1.2.0",` to the composer.json file - I get:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Core dumped: Segmentation fault: 11
Stack trace in /tmp/stacktrace.2219.log
[1]    2219 segmentation fault  hhvm $(brew --prefix)/bin/composer.phar update
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
PHP Stacktrace:

#0  json_decode() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:556]
#1  Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadProviderListings() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php:289]
#2  Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->whatProvides() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:204]
#3  Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:193]
#4  Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:168]
#5  Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromPackage() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:322]
#6  Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->getRulesFor() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:214]
#7  Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Installer.php:461]
#8  Composer\Installer->doInstall() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Installer.php:216]
#9  Composer\Installer->run() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:135]
#10 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259]
#11 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844]
#12 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192]
#13 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Console/Application.php:231]
#14 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123]
#15 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/../src/../src/Composer/Console/Application.php:104]
#16 Composer\Console\Application->run() called at [phar://composer.phar/bin/composer:43]
#17 include() called at [/usr/local/bin/composer.phar:24]
```

Comment: If anyone could help? This is still a problem for me?